# Compare second line of a text with first on next page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Guys please assist in following:
I have texts (strings which I found) and they have same part of text which I have to compare (are on different pages, too). So, here are text(string) examples which I have to check:

```
Conservative Site
Research by Firm Later Produced
```

And second text (which is not on same page) is:

```
Research by Firm Later Produced a lot of Files
```

So, I found both strings, and now I have to compare are they exists. My idea were to compare same part of text (**Research by Firm Later**), but could not achieve to just pickup second line from 1st text and trim part which I do not need for check from second text.
Tried this:

```
String Heading = driver.findElement(By.name("Single Heading")).getText();
String Heading1 = driver.findElement(By.name("Single Heading2")).getText();
    System.out.println(Heading);
    System.out.println(Heading1);
    if (Heading.contains(Heading1) {
    System.out.println("Not same text. Closing test!");
    driver.close();
    }
```

Please, assist and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the first text on the newline:

```
 String lines[] = Heading.split("\\r?\\n");
```

And then check if the second text contains the second line of the first text:

```
 if (Heading.contains(lines[1])) {
    System.out.println("Text found!");
 }
```

You should probably also add a check `if (lines.length > 0)`, for the cases when there is no second line in `Heading`.

*FYI*: normally, variable names are not spelled with a capital letter, so `Heading` would be called `heading`